# .NET foreach checkboxes form into controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have checkboxes which are created using the item.ID from a foreach loop of a table:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="select_@item.ID" name="@item.ID" />
        </td>
```

I've set the form to FormMethod.Get so I can see the parameters passed through to the actionresult e.g. I get this as a query:

```
?474=on&425=on&406=on&445=on
```

I then want to go into the database and remove these entries but I don't know how to separate them as its obviously setting them as individual bools?

This is essentially where ive got to but obviously this wont work as I think its sending them as individual strings? feel like I'm so close:

```
public ActionResult Select(string deleteID)
{
    string[] split = deleteID.Split("=on".ToCharArray());
    int[] selected = Array.ConvertAll(split, s => int.Parse(s));

    foreach (var item in selected)
    {
        Table deletion = db.Tables.Find(selected[item]); 
        db.Tables.Remove(deletion);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeterB worked a treat, thank you just didn't know what to search, should I delete the question or keep it incase people search something similar?

Comment: It's okay to leave it, there are many questions-marked-as-duplicates present. It can even help people find answers faster becase duplicates often use different ways of describing an issue.